# Label and use custom reference for a colorbox

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, tcolorbox

I am trying to reference a tcolorbox that I have created within my latex document. Ideally the in-text reference will have the form BOX 1.1, BOX 1.3, BOX, 3.1 etc. based on the section.

To create my box I followed the example [N 2014-10-10](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) on page 21 of their document. Also, on page 108, of the same document, there is an example of how to label the box but I cannot really make it work.

Can someone please help? Thank you very much.

```
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Box 1 $\mid$ Timeline,
colback=blue!5!white,
colframe=blue!75!black,
colbacktitle=cyan!50!green,
coltitle=blue!25!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
subtitle style={boxrule=0.4pt,colback=cyan!50!red!25!white}]
\tcbsubtitle{1690}
TEXT.
\tcbsubtitle{1896}
TEXT 1.
\tcbsubtitle{1925}
TEXT 2.
\tcbsubtitle{1967}
TEXT 3.
\tcbsubtitle{2000}
TEXT 4.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section,crefname={box}{boxes}]{pabox}[2][]{%
title=Box 1 $\mid$ Timeline,
colback=blue!5!white,
colframe=blue!75!black,
colbacktitle=cyan!50!green,
coltitle=blue!25!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
subtitle style={boxrule=0.4pt,colback=cyan!50!red!25!white},title=Box ~\thetcbcounter $\mid$ #2, label={#1}}
\begin{document}


\section{section title}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{pabox}[mybox]{Timeline}
\tcbsubtitle{1690}
TEXT.
\tcbsubtitle{1896}
TEXT 1.
\tcbsubtitle{1925}
TEXT 2.
\tcbsubtitle{1967}
TEXT 3.
\tcbsubtitle{2000}
TEXT 4.
\end{pabox}
\end{wrapfigure}
Here is a reference with cleveref \cref{mybox} and a capitalized reference \Cref{mybox} and another without cleveref: \ref{mybox}

\end{document}
```

In the preamble of the document I have used the `\newtcolobox` command to define a new type of colored box named `pabox`. The definition of the layout is the same as in the question. I have additionally added the options `auto counter` and `number within=sections` that allow automated numbering of the boxes according to the numbering scheme, that was requested.

Additionally, the title of the box is set 'semi-automatically' with Box and the current number being printed automatically and the text behind the `|` that can be added manually for every box.

In the first optional argument of `pabox` one can add a label that can be used with the usual referencing command like `ref`.

**EDIT:** To automatically print the 'type' in the reference as well (box 1.1 instead of 1.1), I would recomment the package `cleveref`, that I have included in the edited MWE above. Additionally, I have used the option `crefname={box}{boxes}` to tell `cleveref` how to 'call' the boxes in the reference.

To reference the boxes in the text, including their type, one can use `\cref{<label>}` while `\ref{<label>}` still only prints their number. Please also keep in mind the command `\Cref{<label>}` that capitalizes the first letter of the type (usefull for beginnings of sencences).

Addition: `hyperref` can as well be incorporated in this solution to turn references into clickabe hyperlinks. Please keep in mind the correct loading order, as `cleverref` is one of the exceptions that has to be loaded *after* `hyperref`.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see. So it's better to use a common design before I start the main article and then call the design every time I want to use a colorbox. 
Also, could you please let me know if there is a way to use custom reference. In your example to look like 'Here is a reference: BOX 1.1'.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Jespar: If you want to use the same design over and over again, it is indeed easier to define it only once in the preamble. I have also  edited my answer according to your question.

Comment: Your answer, through my 4 years across SE, easily is amongst the top-5 I have seen. Informative and to the point. Nice work!